# python argparser for multiple arguments for partial choices

Tags: python, argparse

I create a argparser like this:

```
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='someDesc')
  parser.add_argument(-a,required=true,choices=[x,y,z])
  parser.add_argument( ... )
```

However, only for choice "x" and not for choices "y,z", I want to have an additional REQUIRED argument. For eg.

```
python test -a x       // not fine...needs additional MANDATORY argument b
python test -a y       // fine...will run
python test -a z       // fine...will run  
python test -a x -b "ccc"       // fine...will run
```

How can I accomplish that with ArgumentParser? I know its possible with bash optparser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To elaborate on the subparser approach:

```
sp = parser.add_subparsers(dest='a')
x = sp.add_parser('x')
y=sp.add_parser('y')
z=sp.add_parser('z')
x.add_argument('-b', required=True)
```

- this differs from your specification in that no `-a` is required.
- `dest='a'` argument ensures that there is an 'a' attribute in the namespace.
- normally an optional like '-b' is not required.  Subparser 'x' could also take a required positional.

If you must use a `-a` optional, a two step parsing might work

```
p1 = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p1.add_argument('-a',choices=['x','y','z'])
p2 = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p2.add_argument('-b',required=True)
ns, rest = p1.parse_known_args()
if ns.a == 'x':
    p2.parse_args(rest, ns)
```

A third approach is to do your own test after the fact.  You could still use the argparse error mechanism

```
parser.error('-b required with -a x')
```

Answer (score 2):

> ArgumentParser supports the creation of such sub-commands with the
>   add_subparsers() method. The add_subparsers() method is normally
>   called with no arguments and returns a special action object. This
>   object has a single method, add_parser(), which takes a command name
>   and any ArgumentParser constructor arguments, and returns an
>   ArgumentParser object that can be modified as usual.

```
ArgumentParser.add_subparsers()
```