# Python argparse conditional requirements

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

How do I set up argparse as follows:

```
if -2 is on the command line, no other arguments are required
if -2 is not on the command line, -3 and -4 arguments are required
```

For example,

```
-2 [good]
-3 a -4 b [good]
-3 a [not good, -4 required]
-2 -5 c [good]
-2 -3 a [good]
```

There are a number of similar questions here, but either they don't address this situation or I don't understand.

Python 2.7 if that matters.

Comment: Make a subparser keyed on -2 that replicates the other commands as optional.  At the top level, link -3 and -4 together.

Comment: Using subparser commands that begin with `-` can be tricky.  `-2` may work, but `-t` or `--two` wouldn't because they look like optionals. But if `-3` is defined as an argument, then `-2` no longer works as a subparser command (or a choice).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A subparser (as suggested in comments) might work.

Another alternative (since `mutually_exclusive_group` can't quite do this) is just to code it manually, as it were:

```
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('-2', dest='two', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-3', dest='three')
    parser.add_argument('-4', dest='four')
    parser.add_argument('-5', dest='five')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if not args.two:
        if args.three is None or args.four is None:
            parser.error('without -2, *both* -3 <a> *and* -4 <b> are required')

    print args
    return 0
```

Adding a little driver to this:

```
import sys
sys.exit(main())
```

and run with your examples, it seems to do the right thing; here are two runs:

```
$ python mxgroup.py -2; echo $?
Namespace(five=None, four=None, three=None, two=True)
0
$ python mxgroup.py -3 a; echo $?
usage: mxgroup.py [-h] [-2] [-3 THREE] [-4 FOUR] [-5 FIVE]
mxgroup.py: error: without -2, *both* -3 <a> *and* -4 <b> are required
2
$
```

Comment: In the absence of better alternatives, doing it manually does seem the best course

Comment: In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917265/python-argparser-for-multiple-arguments-for-partial-choices/17982009#17982009  I suggest a two step parsing.  First use `parse_known_args` to check for the `-2` flag, and if that is missing, use another parser to look for `-3` and `-4`.

Comment: I do not suppose there is a way to affect what --help will print other than setting help for each argument ...

Comment: @Leonid: does not seem to be.  For similar things (never quite this) I've just added explanations in help epilogue.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is pretty hard to achieve that (including a nice help message) while only using the standard argparse functions. You can however easily test it yourself after parsing the arguments. You can describe the extra requirements in the epilogue or so. Note that it is unusual to use numbers as options, I had to use dest='two', since args.2 is not valid syntax.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
   description='bla bla',
   epilog='Note: arguments -3 and -4 are required when -2 is missing')

parser.add_argument('-2', dest='two', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-3', dest='three')
parser.add_argument('-4', dest='four')
parser.add_argument('-5', dest='five')

args = parser.parse_args()

if not args.two and (args.three is None or args.four is None):
    parser.error('arguments -3 and -4 are required when -2 is missing')

print 'Good:', args
```

With these results:

```
[~]: ./test.py -h
usage: test.py [-h] [-2] [-3 THREE] [-4 FOUR] [-5 FIVE]

bla bla

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -2
  -3 THREE
  -4 FOUR
  -5 FIVE

Note: arguments -3 and -4 are required when -2 is missing

[~]: ./test.py -2
Good: Namespace(five=None, four=None, three=None, two=True)
[~]: ./test.py -3 a -4 b
Good: Namespace(five=None, four='b', three='a', two=False)
[~]: ./test.py -3 a
usage: test.py [-h] [-2] [-3 THREE] [-4 FOUR] [-5 FIVE]
test.py: error: arguments -3 and -4 are required when -2 is missing
[~]: ./test.py -2 -5 c
Good: Namespace(five='c', four=None, three=None, two=True)
[~]: ./test.py -2 -3 a
Good: Namespace(five=None, four=None, three='a', two=True)
```

Comment: While `args.2` does not work, `getattr(args,'2')` does.  Arguments  like `-2` are allowed, but add unnecessary complications.

Answer (score 0):

You can define parameter as optional but then you can check it later and raise an exception as below;

```
import argparse

TYPES = ["once", "weekly"]

DAYS = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday",
              "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"]

def take_arg():
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument("-t", "--type", required=True,
                    help="select the type {}".format(TYPES))
    ap.add_argument("-d", "--day", required=False, help="write a day {}".format(DAYS))
    arg = ap.parse_args()
    if arg.type == "weekly":
        if arg.day not in DAYS:
            raise Exception("DayParamNotExist")
    return arg

def main():
    ap_res=take_arg()
    print(ap_res)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```